# Where are return values stored and how/can they be incremented?

Tags: c++, recursion, return, binary-tree, return-value

I've done my fair share of reading and researching but I still don't 100% get it.
For this solution of " Minimum Depth of Binary Tree", the idea of having multiple returns in a recursive function is killing me. I'm not exactly sure how the value for the "minimum depth" is being incremented, and I understand it may have something to do with my misunderstanding of return statements work. Please help, thank you.

```
int minDepth(Node *root) {
        if(!root) return 0;
        
        if(!root->left) return 1 + minDepth(root->right);
        
        
        if(!root->right) return 1 + minDepth(root->left);
      
        return 1+min(minDepth(root->left),minDepth(root->right));
    }
```

Comment: It's incremented by the "1 +". The number of return statements doesn't change the nature of recursion. Play computer with pencil and paper: trace the execution, indent each recursive call, unindent each return, writer down all the values/return values.

Comment: ***the idea of having multiple returns in a recursive function is killing me*** Remember when the execution hits any return the function is done.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I'm starting to get the gist of it. It's being incremented by 1 + whatever is to come from recursively calling the function with the next node. Something along those lines right?

Comment: Yes. Step through in your debugger and watch what it does. That’s the only way to really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, logically, what you have above could just as well have been written

```
int minDepth(Node *root) {

    int result;

    if(!root) 
        result = 0;
    else if(!root->left) 
        result = 1 + minDepth(root->right);
    else if(!root->right) 
        result = 1 + minDepth(root->left);
    else
        result = 1 + min(minDepth(root->left), minDepth(root->right));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution was a bit more helpful. Thank you. Having a variable that more overtly stores the " incrementation" helps me see it better. In the solution I originally posted.. I wasn't sure if the incremented value would be kept despite their being no variable to actually store it in.